# How to mock dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore for the specific url in DOJO?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dojo, qunit

I'm looking for a way to mock the dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore which retrieves json by provided url.

I want to write unit tests for Dojo code without running application server, so the D.O.H. framework is not suitable here as far as I understood.

I'm just looking a possibility to interfere in dojo initialization flow from an other js file in order to put mock for the dojo.data.

Could anyone suggest something, or a better way for doing automated testing to cover dojo code?

Finally I've found a way to do it:
In the js file you want to interfere from, I've added the following:

```
require(['dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore'], function (item) {
    dojo.data = {
        ItemFileReadStore: function (options) {
            return { your implementation here ... };
        }
    };
});
```

Better decisions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Dojo provides the `dojo/request/registry` module as a means of registering providers to handle requests based on criteria such as its URL. This is really useful for mocking endpoints, especially when doing automated testing. For example, if I wanted to mock the url '/foo' so I could return static data anytime a request is made to this endpoint, I could do the following:

```
require([
    'dojo/request/registry',
    'dojo/Deferred'
], function (request, Deferred) {
    request.register('/foo', function () {
        var deferred = new Deferred();

        deferred.resolve({
            identifier: "name",
            items: [
                { name: "Bob"},
                { name: "Sally"},
                { name: "Nancy"}
            ]
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    });
});
```

Anytime a request is made to the URL we defined, in this case '/foo', it will be serviced by this function instead of actually initiating an XHR request. At this point, I could create an ItemFileReadStore and set its `url` parameter to '/foo' and it would always receive the data specified by the registry handler function above.

One more thing: if you are looking to write unit tests or functional tests, you should check out [Intern](https://theintern.github.io/). It's the successor to D.O.H. and allows for much more flexibility when writing unit tests or functional tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @bitpshr! I've tried to intercept http request made by ItemFileReadStore, but without success. But it works if I use request.get('url'). Any thoughts?